# Проблема с авторизацией, а именно с сессией

Tags: php, сессия, авторизация, orm

Написал на php авторизацию для сайта. Простая самая, логины и пароли хранятся в БД. Суть проблемы: при авторизации создается сессия которая доступна только на странице авторизации, на других страницах сайта сессия не доступна.

Например, на странице авторизации можно вывести имя пользователя при помощи echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login; А вот уже на любой другой - не выводит,хотя должно. Из-за этого я не могу дальше развивать сайт. Ибо он не запоминает что пользователь **авторизован**.

Адрес сайта sampwar.tk

Файлы авторизации также прикрепляю http://rgho.st/82NtGjZvF 
( p.s. для работы с бд использую библиотеку RedBeanPHP )

Данный баг можно воспроизвести введя логин и пароль на сайте Chestniy555(логин) Chestniy555(пароль) и перейдя на главную, вы увидите что поле для авторизации не пропало, хотя по условию если сессия передана - они заменяются текстом "Вы авторизованы, name"

Comment: Куки включены? Сессия сохраняется локально на диске? `session.save_path` переменная

Comment: да,  на хостинге все это включено, проверял первым делом

Comment: Вы про функцию session_start() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php забыли видимо.

Comment: Нет, не забыл, у него она в подключаемом файле прописана. В целом я  рекомендую сделать максимально простой и заранее рабочий пример и потестировать его, вдруг в настройках сервера беда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в серверной части на хостинге. Тех. поддержка разобралась.